# .gitignore not working with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, gitignore

I cannot get `.gitignore` to work with *Visual Studio 2019* Community.

[image]

Above is an image of the "Team Explorer" tab showing a portion of the list of files which are to be committed. The directory in which these files appear, x64\Debug, is under  C:\Users\*username*\Source\repos\Tetris_System\Tetris_Game.  C:\Users\*username*\Source\repos\Tetris_System contains the `.git` and `.vs` folders and the `.gitignore` file.

I have a very simple `.gitignore` file with a single line in it:

```
*.obj
```

My understanding is, that this single line should remove all the `*.obj` files from the commit list. Shouldn't those `*.obj` files disappear from the list?

From previous commits, all those `*.obj` are on the GitHub repository.

Comment: No. `.gitignore` is just for file that are not tracked (if you think about it twice, it makes sense because you don't want that a tracked file stopped to be committed because you make a mistake with a rule). You have to untrack them before it takes effect.

Answer (score 9):

The `.gitignore`-file only works on untracked files.

Git sees *every file* in your working copy as one of *three* things:

1. `tracked` - a file which has been previously staged or committed
2. `untracked` - a file which has not been staged or committed
3. `ignored` - a file which Git has been explicitly told to ignore

If you have *tracked* files, the `.gitignore`-file doesn't works.

To untrack a *single* file, stop tracking the file but not delete it from the system use:

```
git rm --cached filename
```

To untrack *every* file in `.gitignore` (first commit any outstanding code changes, and then run):

```
git rm -r --cached
```

This removes any changed files from the index (staging area), then run:

```
git add .
```

and Commit it:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore file is now working"
```

Comment: When I did `git rm -r --cached` I got `fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?`, so added a pathspec, with `git rm -r --cached .`  Then I got a very long output of files being `rm`d. I entered your next two commands, and it seems to have worked.