# Not able to ignore .exe files using gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

So I want to push my cpp codes on github without the `.exe` file generated.So in my `.gitignore` file I have added this command : `*.exe`.But it doesnt't seem to be working as exe files are still there in my code.I am using VSCode to push and track my changes.

Here is screenshot of my directory:

[image]

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Were those .exe files already committed?  If so, changing the .gitignore doesn't make them disappear.  You can delete them, and then any new .exes will be ignored.

Comment: @user2740650 Yes that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following commands to apply the changes in the **.gitignore** file:

```sh
git rm -rf --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push
```

This method removes all files from the repository to enforce ignore rules. Then, following the ignore rules, the files are scanned again and the files to be tracked/untracked are marked.

---

###### References

- [Git keeps adding files in .gitignore on first commit and push to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70536757/15032688)
- [Recommended ignore rules for C/C++ programming](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/C++.gitignore)